# When to use parenthesis in knockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm aware that you use paranthesis in knockoutjs for the ff:
* Unrapping observable function in code
* Dive into objects with declarative binding

or when you have an object person with certain properties for ex:
* person().firstname
* person().age
(The rightmost property doesn't need a parenthesis)

Now I have this kind of html/js:

```
<section>
      <label>
        <input data-bind="checked: displayGuitars" type="checkbox" />
         Display Guitars
      </label>
      <div data-bind="fadeVisible: displayGuitars(), fadeDuration: 250">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
          <li>
            <span data-bind="text: model"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div data-bind="dump: $data, enable: false"></div>
    </section>
<script>



  ..................................some code

   ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // Start visible/invisible according to initial value
        var shouldDisplay = valueAccessor();
        $(element).toggle(shouldDisplay);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        // On update, fade in/out
        var shouldDisplay = valueAccessor(),
            allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
            duration = allBindings.fadeDuration || 500; // 500ms is default duration unless otherwise specified

        shouldDisplay ? $(element).fadeIn(duration) 
            : $(element).fadeOut(duration);
    }
};


var vm = (function () {

    var data = mockdata.getProducts();
    var products = ko.observableArray(data);
    var displayGuitars = ko.observable(false);

    var vm = {
      displayGuitars: displayGuitars,
      products: products
    };

    return vm;
})();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

So basically what it does is that the div with fadeVisible binding is toggled show/hide depending whether the checkbox is checked or not, I tried removing the parenthesis in `<div data-bind="fadeVisible: displayGuitars(), fadeDuration: 250">` and then suddenly the fadeVisible stopped working, the div no longer shows/hides when I check/uncheck the checkbox. My question is why do I need the parenthesis in the div with the fadeVisible binding, and if it does fall on any of the criteria I mentioned above which one is it?

Sir/Ma'am, your answers would be of great help. Thank you++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have an `unwrap` call for your `valueAccessor` in the custom binding. It should look like this

```
init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // Start visible/invisible according to initial value
        var shouldDisplay = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        $(element).toggle(shouldDisplay);
    },
```

This will work in Knockout2.3 If you have an older version its `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` instead.

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/cD8wT/) demonstrating it without the parens. BTW, in the future, when you have the code like this to demonstrate the issue, it helps to put together a fiddle of your own so people can look at the problem quickly.